# Issue in C#: Identifier expected

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am new to C# programming and I have code that is suppose to copy to clipboard the URL source of files to be downloaded. But there is an error, it says "identifier expected". Below is the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    File[] fileArray = this.();  //<<-- in here is the problem
    Clipboard.Clear();

    string str = "";

    File[] fileArray1 = fileArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)fileArray1.Length; i++)
    {
        File file = fileArray1[i];
        str = string.Concat(str, file.downloadURL, Environment.NewLine);
    }
    Clipboard.SetText(str);
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What are you expecting to put in `fileArray`?  A property?  call a method?

Comment: how did that this.(); end up there? what were you trying to do? judging from the code you posted, you dont even need that first File[] fileArray = ...

Comment: It's a syntax error. To call a method of containing class add method identifier (name). To use a field, put in a field name but without parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

*Identifier expected* means that the compiler expects some *identifier*, that is, a name of a variable, a class member, or something like that.

`this` just points to the current object instance; meaning you are going to use a member of the current instance. However, you have to indicate the name of that member after the `.`

Hence, to solve this problem, add an identifier after `this.` and before `()` in the line where the compiler error is displayed. That member will return a value, and that value will be stored in your `fileArray` variable.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I will try to find out what is this identifier c# is expecting. I'm learning.

Comment: Hello sir, your answer clarifies my issue but still I can't resolve it.

Comment: @arnel: You'll need to provide us with more information in order to help you. As D. Stanley has asked you already: What do you want to store in the `fileArray` variable?

Comment: Hello again sir, the fileArray should contain what is in the FileListBox complete with its url path (file.downloadURL). I have just taken this code from a decompiler, that's why it is not also clear to me. But I really want this code or function implemented in my soft.

Comment: @arnel: 1) What is the type of your `FileListBox`, and what type are its items of? 2) Taking code from a decompiler is not a good way to start coding. Please take the time to learn C# at a suitable degree so you *could* write code of the same complexity yourself from scratch. Then you can look into taking code from other sources (including decompiled code) again, if you want to find out something specific. (Do note the legal implications, though.)